# Host Content Provider as a Background Service

Tags: android, service, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to utilize content providers to share data between my app flavors. The problem is, from my understanding the content provider needs to be hosted as an authority on one app. My use case is that if I install any one of the app flavors, there should be a content provider to access, like some sort of service in the background. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `the content provider needs to be hosted as an authority on one app. ` ??¿???¿

Comment: That's how I currently have it set up but I was asking if there was a way around it to accomplish what I asked in the question

Comment: I did not understand that sentence.  But you cleared up nothing.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to clarify. My use case is I have 5 separate apps that I want to share data no matter which order they are installed in and regardless of how many are installed. But from what I understand, a content provider needs to be declared and hosted on one app as you mentioned. So if App A would be the one hosting it, then I couldn't access the shared provider if I had installed App B correct? Is there a way that I can access the shared content provider no matter which app I install?

Comment: If you have five separate apps then every app can have its own content provider. It can be the same content provider code for all. Only the authority needs to be a little different. Now please start again. Further you first spoke of flavours and now of separated. Pretty confusing...

Comment: `a content provider needs to be declared and hosted on one app as you mentioned. ` I did not say or suggest such.

Comment: `So if App A would be the one hosting it, then I couldn't access the shared provider if I had installed App B correct? ` ??? That question does not make sense as the scenario is not complete.

Comment: Apologies again, I'm trying to not make it confusing. I realized I used the term flavors very loosely. It is indeed 5 separate apps. If the authority is different as you suggested, would all 5 apps have access to the same database where the content is stored?

Comment: It is to you to decide where these apps store their data. And you program the ContentProvider. So at the moment you are the only one in the world that can answer that question.

Comment: I'm a bit new to coding with Android so apologies for the confused behavior and I appreciate the help. I tried changing the authority but the apps can't find it if I uninstall the main provider. 
`E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.company.apps.shared.SharedContentProvider` 
This is the link I used for reference for the content provider code.
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/contentprovider/android-content-provider-example/

Comment: You never said that there was a main provider. If an app is not installed then its content provider is not installed either. It is unclear what you want with your providers.

Comment: In short, I want a shared place where any of the 5 apps can store and look up data, regardless of how many there are. Is there a way to accomplish that using content providers? I was under the assumption that there had to be a main content provider declared.

Comment: You can store data in the cloud.

Comment: In my case, the data needs to be stored locally and not by cloud so unfortunately I cannot do that.